# Bulk change hyperlinks

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Is there a feature somewhere for notifying/making bulk updates to hyperlinks?

I have moved a website recently that has a fair number of links on StackOverflow. I don't really want to go around manually updating those links, or trigger them to be nofollow. It seems like there should be a better way.

BTW, my example is: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net -> http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: I'm afraid Stack Overflow won't be the only place where the nice Joda date-time is linked...

Comment: (It's ["only" 1,590 posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*joda-time.sourceforge.net*%22), not counting comments...)

Comment: Unfortunately, [there are rate limits for editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/257345), so although you could automate it with Greasemonkey, you'd have to put in 1 minute or so delays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Any such edits need to be made manually.

If you are going around doing manual edits, I would suggest to start with posts having the [maximum number of views](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*joda-time.sourceforge.net*%22+views%3A8000) and moving downwards. This will benefit most people as the most viewed  posts are the most likely ones to turn up in search results.

Comment: Any way to make this a feature request then?

Comment: @JodaStephen Automated link updation? I dont see it happening but if you can come up with a concrete idea with support, then go ahead and post a separate [meta-tag:feature-request]. Dont let me stop you!

Comment: The team could definitely do this, they did it to update imgur URLs once they got dedicated hosting. But they will probably be reluctant to do so, given the risk of it breaking things. Like Asheesh says, may be worth asking, @Joda.

Comment: I updated the top 20 or so. The rest will have to manage with the 5 second redirect.